# Is there a simpler way in bash to pass environment variable to second bash script?

Tags: bash

In my environment:

```
THE_KEY="Bearer ABCDEFGHI"
```

and here is some_script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
./yet_other_script.sh "$(echo $THE_KEY)"
```

which calls `yet_other_script.sh` such that parameter $1 is `Bearer ABCDEFGHI`

Is there a simpler way than `"$(echo $THE_KEY)"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
./yet_other_script.sh "$(echo $THE_KEY)"
```

with:

```
./yet_other_script.sh "$THE_KEY"
```

#### More details

Consider a directory with these files:

```
$ ls file*
file  file1  file2  file3
```

Define the variable:

```
$ TheKey="a    file?"
```

Now, watch what `echo $TheKey` does:

```
$ echo $TheKey
a file1 file2 file3
```

The multiple spaces between `a` and `file` have been collapsed.  This is the result of *word splitting*.  Also, the string has been subjected to *pathname expansion* resulting in `file?` being replaced by the names of files.

In sum, unless you explicitly want the shell to perform expansions, always put your shell variables in double-quotes:

```
$ echo "$TheKey"
a    file?
```

That's not all: *Command substitution* removes trailing newlines from the output of the command.  For example:

```
$ TheKey=$'abc\n\n\n'
$ echo "$(echo "$TheKey")"
abc
$
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to pass a value from one script to another:

1. As a parameter: `./script.sh "$key"` - the value is available as `$1` within `script.sh`.
2. On standard input: `echo "$key" | ./script.sh` - the value can be read for example using the `read` built-in command.
3. As an exported variable:

   ```
   export KEY
   ./script.sh
   ```

   `$KEY` is then available with the same name in `script.sh`.
4. Passing an indirect reference such as a filename where the value or even the assignment (`key=value`) is stored.

The naming conventions are intentional: by convention upper case names should only be used for exported variables.